# golang sql.open() expects 0 arguments got 1

Tags: mysql, sql, go, arguments

I am trying to connect to a mysql database I have locally, using golang, it builds just fine but running it gives me the following error:

> panic: sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1

My connection looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func DBConn() {
    team := "software"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:12345678@tcp(localhost:3306)/flexlocal")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("this is where it all went wrong")
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

According to my research this is how it works however it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Is this all of your code? The error seems to say that you are trying to run a query and pass an argument that is not expected.

Comment: Doesn't look like issue in above snippet. To check if database connection is established you can do `err = db.Ping()`.

Comment: Can you show all your code?

Comment: As the prior comments suggest, the program you're running may differ from the source code you posted. Try `go run <filename>` eg `go run main.go`

Answer (score 1):

Please try dbconn function to connect with mysql in go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
    func dbConn(setDatbaseInstance string) (db *sql.DB) {
        dbDriver := "mysql"
        dbUser := "*****"
        dbPass := "*****"
        dbName := "*****"
        db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@tcp("+setDatbaseInstance+":3306)/"+dbName)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n DB_ERROR_CONNECTION\n", err.Error());
            // return err.Error()
        }else{
             fmt.Println("Connection Established")
        }
        erro:=db.Ping()
        if erro!=nil {
         //do something here
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n DB_PING_ERROR_CONNECTION\n", erro.Error());
        }


        return db
    }
```